# ListView that shows multiple columns of one row instead of multiple rows

Tags: android, listview

Listview of row 1

"column 1"

"column 2"

"column 3"

Is there a way to show multiple columns on a row. Right now I can list multiple rows in the list view. I am looking at preferenceactivity and I want to achieve something similar to that.  I want each column to be clickable.

EDIT: Some clarification.

Currently I have a listview that populates each row from my database.

ListView

"row 1"

"row 2"

"row 3"

etc...

When I click any of these items on the ListView in, for example, "row 2" it calls an activity that lists all the columns in the row into a textview. What I want to achieve is to list each columns in a listview fashion. So when "row 2" is clicked it should bring me to a view like this.

displays:

"column 1"

"column 2"

"column 3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on your EDIT, perhaps you are looking for a "ExpandableListView" ?

Comment: Somewhat. When the row is clicked it want it open a new view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to achieve, but you could use a horizontal LinearLayout as a row in the vertical LinearLayout you already have. Do you need the whole column to be clickable as a single entity? If you only need clickable elements aligned in columns like a PreferenceActivity, I would use a GridLayout instead.

Answer (score 1):

use [gridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) to do somthing like this :

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); // see 

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        //here, switch position, set the row & column content

    }
});
```

I think this is the best way for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to search for is HorizantalListView.

It's a custom control made by someone. It's so popular.

All android developers use it.

You will find a woking sample on the internet.

you need sometime to understood it. because at some point you need to modify it. As item click listener on it needs some trick to achieve.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar by wrapping all elements of your row in a LinearLayout, giving it a `android:weightSum`. Give each element some `android:layout_weight` and `android:layout_width="0dp"`. It works nicely though is not most elegant..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to do something like this:

---

Listview:

row 1

"column" "column" "column"

row 2

"column" "column" "column"

row 3

"column" "column" "column"

---

and want every column to be clickable without the row "absorving" the click as whole.

Well, you can use a "table layout" that behaves better for that.

You can, however, still achieve this by doing it manually on a list view like this:

1) Create a adapter that spits a row layout (on getView() method) with three views horizontally ("column" "column" "column")

2) Make sure to set each of the three views with clickable="true" on the row XML, and register a listener for each one of the views with setOnClickListener.

3) Disable their parent layout click on your xml.

4) Do not register a onItemClickListener for the list view object (or register a onItemClickListener that just returns false, bleeding the touch to the view under it), and use the created adapter on your list view. You should get the desired effect.